# How can I change the text color of an Ant Design Radio component when it is disabled

Tags: antd

I want to change the text color when an Ant Design Radio button is disabled. I have been trying things like this...

```
.ant-radio[disabled]:active {
    color: $g06;
}
```

Which haven't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the folowing css.

```css
.ant-radio-disabled + span {
    color: #ea6262;
}
```

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]